# Karaf bundles are not coming up ,Unable to start bundle

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, declarative-services

I am Unable to start bundle . While starting bundle

error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:

```
    Error starting bundle 426: Could not resolve module: com.sample.eventFilter [426]
    Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.someother.service; version="[1.80.0,2.0.0)"



Unsatisfied Requirements:
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.someother.service)(&(version>=1.8.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.hadoop.conf)(&(version>=3.80.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))))"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.hadoop.hbase)(&(version>=3.80.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))))"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client)(&(version>=3.80.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))))"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util)(&(version>=3.80.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))))"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.hadoop.security)(&(version>=3.80.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))))"
osgi.service; filter:="(objectClass=com.someother.service)"; effective:="active"; resolution:="optional"
Declarative Services
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple root causes:

1. The required bundles are not installed AND active
2. The required bundles are not the correct version
3. The bundles do not have the Export-Package settings needed for 'com.sample.eventFilter'